# Calculation of phonon dispersion

Tags: density-functional-theory

I have a couple of conceptual questions regarding the calculation of phonon dispersions. I wish to calculate the phonon dispersion of Nickel with my lattice vectors given by [111], [1-10] and [11-2] (though my lattice vectors are non-orthogonal to minimize the number of atoms. My lattice vectors are 2.48901587 0 0, 1.244507935 2.155550974 0, 0 0 40). I also have ~15 A vacuum in my cell. I seem to be getting incorrect phonons for this structure but my results are correct if I choose a FCC unit cell with 4 atoms. My questions are summarized below:

- Do I have to make any changes to my calculations because I have vacuum in my cell?
- I see that calculating force constants (using small displacement method), and hence phonons, requires the creation of supercells. What should they ideally be? Would it be wrong if I just use 1x1x1 cell?

I have attached the results I'm obtaining. The first figure is for the Ni unit cell and the second figure is for the Ni cell with vacuum.

[image: Phonon dispersion for Ni FCC unit cell]

[image: Phonon dispersions for Ni cell with vacuum]

Comment: What method are you using to compute these curves?

Comment: DFPT: the linear response method. I'm using VASP to get these.

Comment: And, I'm using Phonopy for post-processing.